# python find function always gives -1 with .upper()

Tags: python

I was trying to write a parsing routine and use the `find` function.  But it always gives me a -1 no matter what I search for.

```
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]

for word in doc_list:
    word.upper()
    word.find("A")
```

Output:

```
'THE LEARN PYTHON CHALLENGE CASINO.'
-1
'THEY BOUGHT A CAR'
-1
'CASINOVILLE'
-1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.upper()` does not modify the string, it returns a new string.

Use it like this instead:

```py
for word in doc_list:
  print(word.upper().find('A'))
```

Output:

```
6
12
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `upper()` method doesn't change the string, you could apply the  `upper()` method to the string and reassign it to the variable.

```
for word in doc_list:
    word = word.upper()
    word.find("A")
```